# GNU Emacs Prolog mode

Tags: emacs

I to install the SWI Prolog mode for Emacs.

After downloading the plugin (prolog.el version 1.25), how should I install it?

I found this installation guide: https://bruda.ca/emacs/prolog_mode_for_emacs

Comment: hi there, Wanted to ask for some clarification, what kind of trouble are you running into with the guide? Can you provide any additional details?

Comment: I downloaded the prolog.el file and put it in /usr/lib/emacs/site-lisp and where should I put my code in order to run without problems and how to consult my .pl file

Comment: Quoting: *"In a nutshell, place the downloaded file where Emacs can see it, and insert into your `~/.emacs` the following lines:"*... Then all you have to do is copy and paste... You might need to go over this guide of yours once again. :)